# Auto scrolling to element in scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 5 elements that are within a div larger than the screen (on a mobile phone).

I want the user to be able to click on one of the elements and have that element scroll to the centre of the screen.

I've tried writing this with jQuery myself, but I can't seem to get the logic quite right. I've got it kind of moving but the element selected doesn't go to the centre of the screen.

Here's a Fiddle of what I have do far: http://jsfiddle.net/geQ64/1/

Here's the JS from the fiddle also:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

    $('.tab-3').trigger('click');

    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 651) {

        $('.ul-wrap').scrollLeft( $('.tab-3').offset().left );
    }    

});



$('.single-tabs').on('click', function() {

    var offset = $('.tabs').width();
    offset = offset/5;
    var center = offset/2;

    var tab = $(this).data('tab');
    $('.tabs-content').hide();
    $('.tab'+ tab +'').show();

    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width > 650) {

        var arrow = tab*20-12;
        $('.arrow-up').css('margin-left', '' + arrow + '%');

    } else {
        tab = tab - 1;
        var position = offset * tab - center;
        $('.ul-wrap').scrollLeft(position);

    }



});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix, here's the JS is anyone needs it.

The `- 55` in the `var position` is for an arrow that sits in the centre of the page below the elements I'm moving with this script.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

        $('.tab-3').trigger('click');

        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width < 651) {

            var offset = $('.tabs').width();
            offset = offset/7;
            var center = offset/2;
            var position = offset * 2 + center - 50;

            $('.ul-wrap').animate({
                scrollLeft: position
            }, 200);
        }

    });



    $('.single-tabs').on('click', function() {

        var offset = $('.tabs').width();
        offset = offset/7;
        var center = offset/2;

        var tab = $(this).data('tab');
        $('.tabs-content').hide();
        $('.tab'+ tab +'').show();

        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width > 650) {

            var arrow = tab*20-12;
            $('.arrow-up').css('margin-left', '' + arrow + '%');

        } else {
            tab = tab - 1;
            var position = offset * tab + center - 50;
            $('.ul-wrap').animate({
                scrollLeft: position
            }, 200);

        }
```